# Weird regression line in scatterplot in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression, scatter-plot

Hi guys so my problem is possibly either a stats or a programming issue. I have two xts time series of mostly overlapping time periods and I'm simply plotting a regression of their log differences:

```
   logdiff <- merge.xts(diff(log(ts1)),diff(log(ts2)))
   plot(logdiff[,1],logdiff[,2])
   abline(lm(logdiff[,1]~logdiff[,2]),col=2)
```

which gives me this plot

[image: result]

So just on an intuitive level I would rather the regression line fit the wider range of data points even if this result its giving me is technically the correct one on a least squares basis. Is there any inbuilt capability to do this "broader regression" or do i have to resort to manual fudging?

Comment: In `plot(logdiff[,1],logdiff[,2])`, `logdiff[,1]` corresponds to x and `logdiff[,2]` to y. Your `lm` is specified the other way around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are plotting y as a function of x, but regressing x as a function of y.

Try `abline(lm(logdiff[,2]~logdiff[,1]),col=2)` -- and yes, using column names instead of indices is a good idea.

Comment: doh! thx for the insanely fast answer - it works - i cant even hit accept on your answer yet! cheers